# how to call a function with a submit element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to call a function using an event listener but for some reason, it won't work. I'm not getting any errors in my javascript or HTML, so what's the deal?

```js
// Data
const clicks = document.getElementById('loc');
const input = document.getElementById('input').value;
const check = document.getElementById('check');

var totalClicks = 0;
var wToType = "var loc = 0";

// functions
function checkCode() {
  if (input === wToType) {
    totalClicks += 1
    clicks.textContent = "Lines of code:" + totalClicks;
  }
};

// Event listeners
check.addEventListener("click", checkCode, false);
```

```html
<h1 id="loc">Lines of code: 0</h1><br><br>
<h3 id="wtt">Lets get started with our&nbsp;loc (lines of code) variable.&nbsp;&nbsp;Type "var loc = 0"</h3>
<input type="text" name="myInput" id="input" size="25" required>
<input type="submit" id="check" value="Write line(s) of code">
```

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
const input = document.getElementById('input')
```

in the line 2, and

```
 input.value == wToType
```

in line 11.

Comment: Thanks! ill be sure to watch for stuff like that from now on!

Answer (score 0):

It's better to take the value from your input right during calling the function.
Here is the right JS code:

```
// Data
let clicks = document.getElementById('loc');
const check = document.getElementById('check');

let totalClicks = 0;
let wToType = "var loc = 0";
// functions
function checkCode() {
  const input = document.getElementById('input').value;
  if(input === wToType) {
    totalClicks += 1
    clicks.textContent = "Lines of code: " + totalClicks;                                                                                                                                                          
  }
  
};

// Event listeners
check.addEventListener("click", checkCode, false);
```